# if let can not assign value to a Variable

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am developing an app than can extract data from fitbitapi and show it in a tableview, however when I try to append the data I got from web API to the original model, here is my code

```
for json in jsons.values {
        print("json is \(json)")
        if let Json = json as? [String : Any]{

            var healthData : StepStats? = nil
            if let date = Json["dateTime"] as? String,
                let value = Json["value"] as? Int{
                healthData = StepStats(dateTime : date, value : value as AnyObject)

            }
            if let HealthData = healthData {
                model.append(HealthData)
            }

        }
        else {
            print("Unexpected Error")

        }
```

Every time I run this code, it gives unexpected Error, and Json = nil the initial json is here

```
    {
    dateTime = "2018-04-15";
    value = 0;
},
    {
    dateTime = "2018-04-16";
    value = 6969;
},
}
```

I think it is the formate of the Json data I received not well formatted, or is there anything wrong with my code? Please help me I am new to swift so it may be basic mistake, but any help will be appreciate.

The unparsed Data is like this

```
Optional("{\"activities-steps\":[{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-17\",\"value\":\"7170\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-18\",\"value\":\"6443\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-19\",\"value\":\"11254\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-20\",\"value\":\"5771\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-21\",\"value\":\"33\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-22\",\"value\":\"2697\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-23\",\"value\":\"11\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-24\",\"value\":\"8\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-25\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-26\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-27\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-28\",\"value\":\"389\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-29\",\"value\":\"4916\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-30\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-01\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-02\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-03\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-04\",\"value\":\"1929\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-05\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-06\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-07\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-08\",\"value\":\"2818\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-09\",\"value\":\"6990\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-10\",\"value\":\"6558\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-11\",\"value\":\"15434\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-12\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-13\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-14\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-15\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-16\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-17\",\"value\":\"0\"}]}")
```

Comment: You need to put a variable name in the if let and not a type.  Like this : if let variableName = json as? ....

Comment: @jnwagstaff They are putting a variable name and not a type. It just seems that way due to the misuse of naming the variables starting with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @rmaddy thx for your help I did tried use other variable name, like json, data, jsondata etc. but it does not seem to work.

Comment: @jnwagstaff I did use the variable name in the way you suggested, if let Json = json as? [String : any]

Comment: @chenshiyi While it's best to use standard naming conventions, it certainly has nothing to do with your question. I was simply replying to the first comment to let them know it wasn't relevant.

Comment: Your json isn't a dictionary, it's an array of dictionaries.  Your cast should be `if let json = json as? [[String: Any]]`

Comment: @dan Thx, I have tried this and it runs into error in next line Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will add another answer even if StackOverflow advises me to edit the previous answer, but I cannot fail to notice that adding your "new" unparsed data basically turns this question into a completely different one. Usually you should ask another question and maybe post a comment that you would like to continue in another question. Enough of the meta, now for the answer.

While your "unparsed Data" is technically correct it is still very unhandy in two ways. Linearized optionals end up being escaped, so all your double quotes will be escaped (and there are boatloads of those in correct JSON) and there won't be newlines which looks hard to read on StackOverflow where you should try to keep your lines not too much larger than the width of a typical browser window. The escaped double quotes can be taken care of by simply unwrapping the optional (with an `!`), but adding pretty newlines is a little harder. However since your JSON is basically correct now I can use it to show off some other nicety of the `Codable` protocol. If you run this Playground:

```
import Cocoa

let string = "{\"activities-steps\":[{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-17\",\"value\":\"7170\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-18\",\"value\":\"6443\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-19\",\"value\":\"11254\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-20\",\"value\":\"5771\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-21\",\"value\":\"33\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-22\",\"value\":\"2697\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-23\",\"value\":\"11\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-24\",\"value\":\"8\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-25\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-26\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-27\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-28\",\"value\":\"389\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-29\",\"value\":\"4916\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-04-30\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-01\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-02\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-03\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-04\",\"value\":\"1929\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-05\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-06\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-07\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-08\",\"value\":\"2818\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-09\",\"value\":\"6990\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-10\",\"value\":\"6558\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-11\",\"value\":\"15434\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-12\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-13\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-14\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-15\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-16\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"dateTime\":\"2018-05-17\",\"value\":\"0\"}]}"

let jsonData = string.data(using: .utf8)!

struct Step: Codable {
    let value: String
    let dateTime : Date
}

struct Activity: Codable {
    let steps: [Step]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case steps = "activities-steps"
    }
}

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

do {
    let activity = try decoder.decode(Activity.self, from: jsonData)

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    let data = try encoder.encode(activity)
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This will print out the following pretty printed JSON:

```
{
    "activities-steps" : [
        {
            "value" : "7170",
            "dateTime" : "2018-04-17"
        },
        {
            "value" : "6443",
            "dateTime" : "2018-04-18"
        },
        {
            "value" : "11254",
            "dateTime" : "2018-04-19"
        },
        {
            "value" : "5771",
            "dateTime" : "2018-04-20"
        },
        {
            "value" : "33",
            "dateTime" : "2018-04-21"
        },
        {
            "value" : "2697",
            "dateTime" : "2018-04-22"
        },
        {
            "value" : "11",
            "dateTime" : "2018-04-23"
        },
        {
            "value" : "8",
            "dateTime" : "2018-04-24"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-04-25"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-04-26"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-04-27"
        },
        {
            "value" : "389",
            "dateTime" : "2018-04-28"
        },
        {
            "value" : "4916",
            "dateTime" : "2018-04-29"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-04-30"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-01"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-02"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-03"
        },
        {
            "value" : "1929",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-04"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-05"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-06"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-07"
        },
        {
            "value" : "2818",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-08"
        },
        {
            "value" : "6990",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-09"
        },
        {
            "value" : "6558",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-10"
        },
        {
            "value" : "15434",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-11"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-12"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-13"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-14"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-15"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-16"
        },
        {
            "value" : "0",
            "dateTime" : "2018-05-17"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now this is still unwieldy as a StackOverflow question (usually you probably should whittle it down since it is just boring repetition, but that is ok for a first question), but it is still much easier to digest in this form. And it has hopefully taught you how to build `Codable` structs to represent your data in a really Swifty form and how to format some messy JSON into a more readable format that is easier to digest with your eyes.

It is obvious the JSON was correct since the `JSONDecoder` managed to parse it, but it is also a lot easier to judge for you as a human what it should look like when you see it in pretty printed form.

Like this your `activity` should be easy to process and to use it in a `TableView`, so I hope there is at least some of your problem have been solved by this.

Answer (score 0):

Your printout looks almost like JSON, however it is not. I guess you print out an object derived from the ill conceived `JSONSerialization` which will decide by itself what it parses from a string. This can be controlled much more easily and in a much more versatile way by applying the `Codable` protocol. Given that you can run the following Playground

```
import Cocoa

let jsonData = """
[
    {
        "dateTime":"2018-04-15",
        "value":0
    },
    {
        "dateTime":"2018-04-16",
        "value":6969
    }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct HealthData: Codable {
    let date: Date
    let value: Int

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date = "dateTime"
        case value
    }
}

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

do {
    let datas = try decoder.decode([HealthData].self, from: jsonData)
    print(datas)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

which greatly simplifies your parsing strategy since most of it is taken care of by the `JSONDecoder` for which you can even specify the date formatter. Please feel free to add your *actual* JSON if my guess has been wrong, but please post the content of the `String` you got from your service instead of some half parsed structure.

Comment: (["activities-steps": <__NSArrayI 0x7fdda2e0a7d0>(
{
    dateTime = "2018-04-15";
    value = 0;
},
{
    dateTime = "2018-04-16";
    value = 6969;
}

Comment: that is the original data I received it is a key- value pair and I extracts its value and suppose it is json. it is that due to my JsonSerliazation?

Comment: What you posted was (most of) a serialized version of the _result_ of your `JSONSerialization`. `JSONSerialization` is a Cocoa/Objective-C parser that will produce `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, `NSString` and the like. Those will transfer to Swift only as optionals and untyped `Any`s. They are a pain to work with (as you noticed) and the `Codable` protocol gives you much more Swifty capabilities. Please post your raw JSON-output (before `JSONSerialization`) as an update to your question (not in a comment) if you need more help.

Comment: If you use Alamofire and `responseJSON` then you should switch to `responseString` and roll your own `Codable` as above. It will spare you a bunch of `if let`s and casts.

Comment: Sry I am new to stackoverflow, so did not know how to reply properly, I am going to edit my answer now, however when I try to force assiagn json to Json it appears that could not cast NSArray to NSDictionary. Thx for your help and hope this can help you identify my problem